# What is the difference between a FixedThreadPool and ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool

Is there a difference between configuring a Thread pool using the following configurations:

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
```

versus doing:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
executor.setThreadNamePrefix("thread-pool");
executor.initialize();
```

I am not interested in configuring the thread pool during runtime (which is I think the main driver for using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`).

Comment: I don't see how they could be equivalent: `newFixedThreadPool(...)` must return an object that implements the `ExecutorService` interface, but `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` does _not_ implement that interface. Personally, I would not depend on `newFixedThreadPool(...)` to do anything different from what its documentation says it will do: I.e., it will return an `ExecutorService`, that uses a fixed number of threads, that has an unbounded queue, etc. The exact class of the object that it returns _could_ change from one version of the library to  another, but it still should keep the same promises.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Both implement the `Executor` interface

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` will create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `corePoolSize` of 50, [`maxPoolSize` of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java#L89) and [`keepAlive` of 60 seconds](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java#L91).

Meanwhile `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50)` will set both `corePoolSize` and `maxPoolSize` to 50 and `keepAlive` of 0 seconds (see Java source code).

Comment: I think he is talking about `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` from Spring. And not that this method returns `ThreadPoolExecutor` which is completly different from `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki To make sure I understand, when core and max pool sizes are equal, can the pool only support 50 concurrent requests ?

Comment: @GdgamesGamers `maxPoolSize` is the limit. `corePoolSize` is the number of threads kept in the pool even when idle.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki So the difference between the two approaches is that with the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` I can configure smaller number of idle threads from the start but it can expand some maximum whereas the `newFixedThreadPool` starts out with the maximum number of threads. Is this correct ?

Comment: @GdgamesGamers yes, it's a "fixed" pool after all :)

Answer (score 8):

`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is a class from Spring Framework. On the other hand `Executors::newFixedThreadPool` creates a standard `ThreadPoolExecutor` thread pool that comes from standard Java and is available since Java 5.

From docs of [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) :

> JavaBean that allows for configuring a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) in bean style (through its "corePoolSize", "maxPoolSize", "keepAliveSeconds", "queueCapacity" properties) and exposing it as a Spring `TaskExecutor`.
>
> ....
>
> This class implements Spring's [`TaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) interface as well as the [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html?is-external=true) interface, with the former being the primary interface, the other just serving as secondary convenience. For this reason, the exception handling follows the `TaskExecutor` contract rather than the `Executor` contract, in particular regarding the [`TaskRejectedException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskRejectedException.html).

Notice that `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` implements many Spring interfaces like  `Aware`, `BeanNameAware`, `DisposableBean`, `InitializingBean` which makes it easier to work with such pool as a Spring bean.

Also have a look at [Karol Dowbecki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260217/what-is-the-difference-between-a-fixedthreadpool-and-threadpooltaskexecutor/57260340#57260340) which correctly points out differences on those pools parameters.